# Sass multi-state navigation bar issue

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have a navigation bar, where the buttons have a hover state but also need to be "active" on their respective page. Since this navigation bar is part of an include, I decided to do the active state via a class on the body tag, as in `.dashboard .dashboard-button`. So I have the hover and this.

I was trying to figure out the most streamlined way to do this with Sass/Compass. I created a couple of mixins:

```
@mixin nav-button-on($icon) {
    background-color: #2f3684; // Old browsers
    @include filter-gradient($offwhite, #E5E5E5, vertical); // IE6-9
    @include background-image(url('../images/'+$icon+'-on.png'),linear-gradient(top, $offwhite 0%, #E5E5E5 100%));
    border-bottom: $borderbottom solid #F31A35;
    a { color: $red;}
}
@mixin nav-button($icon){
    background-color: #fff; // Old browsers
    @include filter-gradient(#fff, #fff, vertical); // IE6-9
    @include background-image(url('../images/'+$icon+'.png'),linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #fff 100%));
}
```

And then in the LI where the buttons are defined, I have

```
 li {
 &.dashboard { 
            @include nav-button('dashboard'); 
        }
        .dashboard &.dashboard { 
            @include nav-button-on('dashboard'); 
            &:hover {
                 @include nav-button-on('dashboard'); 
            }
        }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body class="dashboard">
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
    <li class="first dashboard"><a href="/index.php">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li class="challenges"><a href="/challenges.php">Challenges &amp; Teams</a></li>
    <li class="goals"><a href="/goals.php">Goals</a></li>
    <li class="activity"><a href="/my-activity.php">My Activity</a></li>
    <li class="destinations"><a href="/destinations.php">Destinations</a></li>
    <li class="fitness last"><a href="/fitness-resources.php">Fitness Resources</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This seems a bit convoluted, I was wondering if anyone had any advice to streamline this at all.

NOTE: I had to add the white-to-white gradient, since when hovering over a solid-color background with the gradient hover state caused a flash.

Comment: How do you get formatted, indented code in a comment?

Comment: You don't. Anything more than a short snippet should be added to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things to improve here:

1. Are you really dealing with that hierarchy of `dashboard` classes? For example, you're currently compiling to:

   ```
   li.dashboard {
       ...
   }
   li .dashboard li.dashboard {
       ...
   }
   ```

   This seems wrong or at least poorly structured. Perhaps you could simplify things here.
2. Assuming you need this for each of your nav `<li>` elements, DRY it up with an iterated mixin:

   ```
   li {
       @each $item in dashboard, challenges, goals, activity, destinations, fitness {
           &.#{$item} { 
               @include nav-button($item); 
           }
           .#{$item} &.#{$item} { 
               @include nav-button-on($item); 
               &:hover {
                   @include nav-button-on($item); 
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. But #2 is not actually the best way. Use placeholders rather than mixins for this kind of stuff, or combine the two. I'd do something like this:

   ```
       %nav-button {
           background-color: #fff; // Old browsers
           @include filter-gradient(#fff, #fff, vertical); // IE6-9
       }

       %nav-button-on {
           background-color: #2f3684; // Old browsers
           @include filter-gradient($offwhite, #E5E5E5, vertical); // IE6-9
           border-bottom: $borderbottom solid #F31A35;
           a { color: $red;}
       }

       @mixin li-image($icon) {
           @include background-image(url('../images/'+$icon+'.png'),linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #fff 100%));
       }

       @mixin li-image-on($icon) {
           @include background-image(url('../images/'+$icon+'-on.png'),linear-gradient(top, $offwhite 0%, #E5E5E5 100%));
       }

       @each $item in dashboard, challenges, goals, activity, destinations, fitness {
           body.#{$item} li, li.#{$item}:hover {
               @extend %nav-button-on;
               @include li-image-on($item);
           }
           li.#{$item} {
               @extend %nav-button;
               @include li-image($item);
           }
       }
   ```

Compare the outputs and maintainability of these and I think you'll find this quite a bit more streamlined!

Comment: thanks.  what I am trying to get, ultimately, is `.dashboard li.dashboard`, since when displayed on the page with `body class="dashboard"`, the li with the same class should be "on", as well on "on" when hovered on any other page.  Great suggestions, I will try it.

Comment: This setup is genius. I need also, as I said above, to get the hover state as the normal state when a given LI is inside a BODY with the same class, so I edited the loop like so: http://pastebin.com/uWcr6gGy Does this make sense to you?

Comment: You'll need to have the body.dashboard outside the li selector. See my edited #3 above for a simplified version.

Answer (score -1):

You have a wrong `}` after `@include nav-button('dashboard');`

try it:

```
li {  
    &.dashboard {   
        @include nav-button('dashboard');  
        .dashboard &.dashboard {   
            @include nav-button-on('dashboard');     
            &:hover {  
                @include nav-button-on('dashboard');   
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, probably the copy and paste to this forum did that. My code works fine, I'm asking if anyone has opinions on streamlining it.